# How can I list Bash's options for the current shell?

Tags: bash, shopt

The Bash interpreter itself has options.

For example, those mentioned on lines 22-23 of [Bash's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#OPTIONS):

> OPTIONS
> All of the  single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command can be used as options when the shell is invoked.   In addition, bash interprets the following options when it is invoked:
> -c ...
> -i ...
> -l ...
> -r ...

I've used a few search patterns in Bash's man page like:

- `/^\s*set`
- `/list`

Is it possible to print a list of these settings that are applied to the current shell?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
printf %s\\n "$-"
```

Will list the single letter options in a single string.

That parameter can also be used like:

```
set -f -- ${-:+"-$-"}
echo *don\'t* *glob* *this*
set +f "$@"
```

To first disable shell `-f`ilename expansion while simultaneously saving a value for `$-` - if any - in `$1`. Next, no globs occur, and last `+f`ilename expansion is once again enabled, and possibly also disabled.

For example, if `-f`ilename expansion was already disabled when the value for `$-` was first saved, then its saved value would be *(at least)*:

```
f
```

And so when `set` is run again, it works out to:

```
set +f -f
```

Which just puts you right back where you started.

```
set +o
```

Will list all `set`table shell options *(see [Jason's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210160/52934) for the `shopt`able - is that a word? - options)* in a form that is safe for shell reentry.  In that way, you can also do:

```
state=$(set +o)
set -some -crazy -options
eval "$state"
```

To save, change, and restore the shell options' state respectively.

To handle `shopt`ions and `set`table options in one go:

```
state=$(set +o; shopt -p) 
#do what you want with options here
eval "$state"
```

You can also call `set` *without* any arguments to add a list of all of the shell's currently set variables - also quoted for reentry to the shell. And you can - in bash - additionally add the command `typeset -fp` to also include all currently declared shell functions. You can lump it all together and `eval` when ready. You can even call `alias` without arguments for more of the same. That... might cover it, though. I guess there is `"$@"` - which you'd have to put in a `bash` array first, I suppose, before doing `set`.

Nope, there's also `trap`. This one's a little funny. Usually:

```
trap 'echo this is my trap' 0
(echo this is my subshell; trap)
```

...will just print *this is my subshell* because the subshell is a new process and gets its own set of `trap`s - and so doesn't inherit any `trap`s but those which its parent has explicitly ignored - *(like `trap '' INT`)*.

However:

```
trap 'echo this is my trap' 0
save_traps=$(trap)
```

`trap` behaves specially when it is the first and *only* command run in a command substitution subshell in that it will reproduce a list of the parent shell's currently set `traps` in a format which is quoted for safe reentry to the shell. And so you can do the `save_traps`, *then* `set` without arguments - and all of the rest already mentioned - to pretty much get a lock on all shell state. You might want to explicitly add `export -p` and `readonly -p` to restore original shell var attributes, though.

Anyway, that's enough.

Comment: thanks, your code works nicely. so to get a full list of all options, you would have to use both `set +o` *and* `shopt` ? (as to `shopt`able being a word, `settable` is used in the man page, so `shoptable` works for me)

Comment: @user4668401 - I think that will do it.

Comment: TL;DR, but +1000 for the 3 lines solution to change an option and put it back 'as it was'.  Thats exactly what one needs when creating scripts or copy/pastable instructions.

Comment: @mikeserv Seems that **-p** option needs to be added when saving state to include `shopt`ions, i.e. `state=$(set +o;shopt -p)`

Comment: Wouldn't this work just as well for capturing the current set options? `set -f -- -$-`?

Comment: @erike yeah. then you can do `set +f "$@"` and watch your `$#` shrink. i like to include an empty string in my first argument like `set -f -- '' +f "${-:+-$-}$@"; echo "$#"; "set$@"; echo "$#"`

Answer (score 22):

Options?: There are three groups of options in bash.

1. The options read or set by the command `set`.
   ( use this command for the manual: `LESS=+/'set \[--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT\]' man bash` )
   All the one-letter options: `abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT`

   Also the options (which have no single letter equivalent):

   ```
   set -o emacs
   set -o history
   set -o ignoreeof
   set -o interactive-comments
   set -o pipefail
   set -o posix
   set -o vi
   ```
2. The options read or set by the command `shopt`.
   ( read the manual with this command: `LESS=+/'shopt \[-pqsu\]' man bash'` )
   The list is quite long but easy to print, use:

   ```
   $ shopt -p
   ```

   or the similar (but not equal):

   ```
   $ shopt
   ```
3. The options that could be set on INVOCATION:
   ( command for the manual: `LESS=+/'^INVOCATION' man bash` )

   All `set` options:

   ```
   bash -abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT
   ```

   All `shopt` options

   ```
   bash -O option
   ```

   Some options that are only meaningful when INVOKING bash:

   ```
   bash -lirsDc
   ```

   And, also (long options):

   ```
   bash --debugger --help --init-file file --rcfile file --login \
        --noediting --noprofile --norc --posix --restricted \
        --verbose --version
   ```

All `set` one letter options and `-ri` are printed with `$-`.

```
-i      Interactive  
Only read with `$-` (if it contains an `i`).
-r      Restricted
Also read with `shopt -p restricted_shell
```

For example:

```
$ echo 'echo $0 $-' | bash -abefhikmprtuvxBCEHPT -lri
```

Calling bash as a login shell is only reported with shopt:

```
-l      Login
read with `shopt -p login_shell`
```

Thus:

```
$ echo 'shopt -p login_shell' | bash -abefhikmprtuvxBCEHPT -lri
shopt -s login_shell
```

The option `-n` can not be tested by any code, as it means: do not execute any code.

---

#### Printing options

The best tool to list the options of the **running** shell, either the ones set with `set` or the ones set with `shopt` is the same `shopt`. To list set options:

```
shopt -o
```

Which acts exactly as `set -o`. Use `shopt -po` to get the same result as `set +o`.

To list shopt options:

```
shopt -p
```

Of which you can choose to print either the ones set `shopt -ps` or unset `shopt -pu`

To get all options. As much as it is possible as many long options and some ( `-sDc` ) on INVOCATION can not be printed:

```
$ echo $-; shopt -p ; shopt -po
```

To store them in a variable:

```
$ storeoptions="$(echo "set -$-"; shopt -p ; shopt -po)"
```

And the variable could be used to set back all the options:

```
$ eval "$storeoptions"
```

Answer (score 21):

From [the `man` page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> shopt
> ...With no options, or with the -p option, a list of all settable options is displayed, with an indication of whether or not each is set.

```
shopt | grep "on$"
```

will print a list of all the enabled options.

Comment: that worked, thanks. Do you you know if this lists the options that are settable by both `set` and `shopt`?

Comment: @user4668401 No, `set` is far more extensive: see [the man page entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin).

Comment: And to check if a single option is on: `shopt <option>`

Comment: checking with `shopt <shoptoption>` only works with ***shopt*** shell options, e.g. it works for `shopt nullglob`, as *nullglob* is a *shopt* shell option. However `shopt pipefail` fails, because *pipefail* is a ***set*** shell option. To check a *set* shell option using the `shopt` command, use `shopt -o <setoption>`; e.g. `shopt -o pipefail` works.

Answer (score 11):

To list all options:

```
set -o
```

To inspect a specific option:

```
set -o | grep <OPTION>
```

Take option `verbose` as an example:

```
$ set -o | grep verbose
verbose         off
```

Answer (score 2):

To inspect a specific option:

```
if shopt -q <OPTION>
then echo '<OPTION> is set'
fi
```